# How to modify the body of a JMS TextMessage using a Transformer in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to transform a message in ActiveMQ Artemis. I want to modify an original message. If modifying the original message is not possible, how to get a modified message in the Forwarded queue?

`Send.java`:

```java
message = JNDIConnection.session.createTextMessage("This is an original msg");
message.setStringProperty("origProp","origVal");
producer.send(message);
System.out.println("Msg sent");
```

`Receive.java`:

```java
TextMessage receivedMessage = (TextMessage) consumer.receive();
Enumeration propertyNames = receivedMessage.getPropertyNames();
while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String propertyName = (String) propertyNames.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Property name: " + propertyName + "; property value: " +receivedMessage.getObjectProperty(propertyName));
}
System.out.println("Actual msg: " + receivedMessage.getText());
```

`ReceiveFrwd.java`:

```java
TextMessage receivedMessage = (TextMessage) consumer.receive();
Enumeration propertyNames = receivedMessage.getPropertyNames();
while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String propertyName = (String) propertyNames.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Property name: " + propertyName + "; property value: " +receivedMessage.getObjectProperty(propertyName));
}
System.out.println("Received msg in frwd queue: " + receivedMessage.getText());
```

`MyCustomTransformer.java`:

```java
private static final Logger logger =  LogManager.getLogger(MyCustomTransformer.class);
@Override
public Message transform(Message message) {
    logger.info("Tranformer invoked");
    ICoreMessage coreMessage = message.toCore();
    coreMessage.putStringProperty("transformed", "true");
    coreMessage.getBodyBuffer().writeString("This is the transformed message content.");
    return coreMessage;
}
```

I did the following steps.

1. Started server
2. Execute Send.java
3. Execute Receive.java
4. Execute ReceiveFrwd.java

Output:
`Receive.java`:

```
Property name: origProp; property value: origVal
Property name: JMSXDeliveryCount; property value: 1
Actual msg: This is an original msg
```

`ReceiveFrwd.java`:

```
Property name: origProp; property value: origVal
Property name: JMSXDeliveryCount; property value: 1
Property name: _AMQ_ORIG_QUEUE; property value: test-divert
Property name: _AMQ_ORIG_ROUTING_TYPE; property value: 1
Property name: transformed; property value: true
Property name: _AMQ_ORIG_ADDRESS; property value: quick-start
Property name: _AMQ_ORIG_MESSAGE_ID; property value: 75
Received msg in frwd queue: This is an original msg
```

`broker.xml`:

```xml
<xml>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:activemq" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-server.xsd">
    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

        <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
        <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
        <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
        <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="tcp">tcp://localhost:61616</acceptor>
        </acceptors>
        <diverts>
            <divert name="test-divert">
                <address>quick-start</address>
                <forwarding-address>quick-start-mod</forwarding-address>
                <transformer-class-name>org.example.MyCustomTransformer</transformer-class-name>
                <exclusive>false</exclusive>
            </divert>
        </diverts>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you see "Tranformer invoked" on the broker? Can you include your `divert` configuration?

Comment: What client library are you using to send the message(s) from `Send.java`?

Comment: @JustinBertram, Added broker.xml
Yes. I see transformer invoked in logs and I could see "transformed" property added in transformer in the RecieveFrwd.java response. 

I am using "artemis-jms-client-all" as client library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is how you're modifying the *body* of the message in your `Transformer` implementation.

First, you must understand how a JMS `TextMessage` is converted to & from a *core* message. In short, the `String` in the text message is written to and read from the body buffer using `writeNullableSimpleString(SimpleString)`. Therefore, when you write your *new* data to the buffer you need to use the same method.

Second, you must clear the buffer of the existing data before you write the new data otherwise when the consumer receives the message it will just read the old buffer data instead of the new data you wrote.

Here's an example based on the code in your question:

```java
@Override
public Message transform(Message message) {
    logger.info("Tranformer invoked");
    ICoreMessage coreMessage = message.toCore();
    coreMessage.putStringProperty("transformed", "true");
    coreMessage.getBodyBuffer().clear();
    coreMessage.getBodyBuffer().writeNullableSimpleString("This is the transformed message content.");
    return coreMessage;
}
```